# ActiveMQ Artemis REST Interface configuration

Tags: rest, activemq-artemis

I'm attempting to add ActiveMQ Artemis' REST interface to my Docker container, and for that I have been following the [official guide](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/rest.html). I generate a `artemis-rest.war` file and move it into my `/opt/artemis/web` folder. Now when I navigate to `http://localhost:8161/artemis-rest/queues/queue_name`, I get a 404. When I try to navigate to other resources listed in the `/opt/artemis/web` like /console/ or /artemis-plugin/ I get at least some sort of a response.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
   `-- main
       `-- webapp
           `-- WEB-INF
               `-- web.xml
       `-- resources
           `-- rest.xml
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.somebody</groupId>
    <artifactId>artemis-rest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ActiveMQ Artemis REST</name>
    <version>2.17.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq.rest</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-rest</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logmanager</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

rest.xml:

```xml
<rest-messaging>
    <server-in-vm-id>0</server-in-vm-id> <!-- deprecated, use "url" -->
    <use-link-headers>false</use-link-headers>
    <default-durable-send>false</default-durable-send>
    <dups-ok>true</dups-ok>
    <topic-push-store-dir>topic-push-store</topic-push-store-dir>
    <queue-push-store-dir>queue-push-store</queue-push-store-dir>
    <producer-time-to-live>0</producer-time-to-live>
    <producer-session-pool-size>10</producer-session-pool-size>
    <session-timeout-task-interval>1</session-timeout-task-interval>
    <consumer-session-timeout-seconds>300</consumer-session-timeout-seconds>
    <consumer-window-size>-1</consumer-window-size> <!-- deprecated, use "url" -->
    <url>vm://0</url>
</rest-messaging>
```

web.xml:

```xml
<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.rest.integration.RestMessagingBootstrapListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Rest-Messaging</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Rest-Messaging</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>rest.messaging.config.file</param-name>
        <param-value>rest.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Have I missed something? Do I need to still need to configure something?
I would have though that that including the .war file would be enough, to at least get an error of some kind.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using the REST interface? In general, I would recommend against using the ActiveMQ Artemis REST interface for 2 main reasons. 1) Your code will not be portable because the ActiveMQ Artemis REST interface is a custom (i.e. not standardized) interface. 2) The STOMP protocol is ubiquitous, simple, standarized, and can be used in almost every circumstance and environment where REST might be used. I recommend you use STOMP in lieu of the ActiveMQ Artemis REST interface if at all possible.

Comment: @JustinBertram Sorry for the long wait, we are planning to use it for integration testing.

Comment: Can you help me understand the use-case for using it your integration testing over something else like STOMP?

Comment: We chose REST because it is the messaging protocol most people are familiar with.

Comment: The problem is that REST is *not* a messaging protocol. It's actually not a protocol at all. It's just an architectural style. It uses HTTP as the protocol which is also not a messaging protocol. This is the problem I was describing in my first comment. Since REST is not a messaging protocol your clients will have to use the messaging protocol which ActiveMQ Artemis has built *on top of* REST which will make your applications non-portable. I recommend that you move to a standardized protocol like STOMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deploy `artemis-rest.war` in `etc/bootstrap.xml`, e.g.:

```xml
   <web bind="http://localhost:8161" path="web">
       ...
       <app url="artemis-rest" war="artemis-rest.war"/>
   </web>
```

The embedded web server won't automatically deploy `artemis-rest.war` just because you put it into the `web` directory.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something.